# How to Exchange Value Between Select Option and Text Input On Conditional

Tags: jquery

Hi I have an optins select "Other" which if user clicks on that the Hidden input box will show up and prompts user to validate the input at [this DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Behseini/L3TqT/2/)

as:

```
   $('#selType').change(function(){
     if($(this).val() == '2') {$('#benOt').show(); }//end of If
       else{$('#benOt').css("display", "none");}   
 });
```

and I do validation as:

```
  if ($('#selType').val() === "2") {
            if ($('#other').val() === "") {
                $('#other').parent().after('<div class="alert alert-danger err"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>This is a Required Field</div>');
                proceed = false;
            } else if (!nameRegexnumber.test($('#other').val())) {
                $('#other').parent().after('<div class="alert alert-danger err"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Data Type Cant Be Number</div>');
                proceed = false;
            } else if (!nameRegexshort.test($('#other').val())) {
                $('#other').parent().after('<div class="alert alert-danger err"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Data Type Cant Be Short</div>');
                proceed = false;
            } else {

            }
        }
```

So far things works fine BUT I need to get the value for Type so if I chose the other how can I get the value from the input box? what I have done was :

```
if (proceed) {
            file_type = $('#selType').val();
                $('#stype').html(file_type);

        }
```

Which make **Type = 2** syntactically correct but logically wrong! Can you please let me know how I can fix this?

Comment: What is `#stype`? I don't see it in your fiddle.

Comment: <div id="stype"></div> at the end of HTML

Comment: Huge $dollar$ mess, I advise you to stick to any kind of JS framework [Backbone / Angular / Knockout].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a conditional when putting the value in `#stype`

```
file_type = $('#selType').val();
$('#stype').html(file_type == '2' ? $('#other').val() : file_type);
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/barmar/L3TqT/6/)

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for your comment but this stops the whole process!

Comment: Sorry, typo, second `?` should obviously be `:`.

Comment: Thanks for edit but I am getting again 2 when the value comes from text input.It works on Select option

Comment: Thanks it is functioning perfectly now